# Continuity of integration as a function of the set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How to prove that if function is integrable then the integral as a function of the set is continuous ?

We assume that the function is nonnegative and function going from arbitrary measure space with nonatomic measure. The topology: on sigma algebra induced by semi-metric where $d(A,B)$= symmetric difference operation.

Comment: Continuous with respect to what topology?

Comment: Oh of course sorry , with topolog on sigma algebra induced by semi-metric where $d(A,B)= symmetric difference operation.

Comment: Please edit your question and revise the statement properly.

Comment: If $f$ is the function, we can always find a simple function $\phi \leq f$ such that $\int f \leq \int \phi + \epsilon$. Then use the fact that $\phi$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: It is enough to show that if $A_n$ is a sequence of sets such that the measure of $A_n$ tends to $0$, then $\int_{A_n} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\to 0$